# Why is the subjunctive used here?

Tags: subjunctives

Is the use of the subjunctive correct in this sentence--

"Though he were the speaker, I would say the same."

Comment: Subjunctive is used for hypothetical situations and here "was" seems to be a better fit. That's what is confusing.

Comment: Subjunctive? Not in modern grammar. "Were" is called 'irrealis' mood. Note that English does not have a subjunctive mood; it was lost in earlier stages of the language. What we do have, though, is a subjunctive clause type that uses a plain form verb, as in "It is vital that I **be** kept informed".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, the sentence is not correct because the opening clause is **not** subjunctive.

It begins with "though", which means "*despite the fact that*..". If something is *fact*, it isn't hypothetical.

A subjunctive statement would begin...

> **If** he were the speaker..."

But it would make no sense to say "If he were the speaker I would say the same" - how can you say the same as something that hasn't been said?

It would make sense to say:

> Though he **was** the speaker, I would **have said** the same.

The subjunctive statement is what you *would have* said, *if* you had been the speaker, not what the actual speaker *did* say in the past.

If you wanted to open with a subjunctive clause, you could say:

> **If** I had been the speaker, I would have said the same.

Comment: Thanks. Such a sentence I spotted in a traditional grammar book. I thought it was off and just to make sure I was right, did I post it here.